# DF return a date column with 2 formats

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column with date, but the outcome is different for the lines, some lines outcomes **ddmmyy** some lines **mmddyy**. The database is all equal **ddmmyy**.

> 12/20/2021 12/21/2021 12/22/2021 12/22/2021 12/27/2021 12/27/2021
> 12/27/2021 12/27/2021 12/27/2021 12/27/2021 12/27/2021 12/29/2021
> 12/31/2021 03/01/2022 03/01/2022 03/01/2022 04/01/2022 06/01/2022
> 06/01/2022

Today, Im changing the code for each format, inverting mm with dd.

```
DezDu = pd.to_datetime((envios.loc[i, "10du"])).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], dayfirst=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
envios['10du'] = pd.to_datetime(envios.10du)

envios['10du'] = envios['10du'].dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')
```

Comment: works! thanks
envios['10du'] = pd.to_datetime(envios['10du'])
envios['10du'] = envios['10du'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the format of the entire column to dd-mm-yy format

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/2016', 1: '1/26/2015'}})
df['DOB_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df

    DOB         DOB_1
0   26/1/2016   26/01/2016
1   1/26/2015   26/01/2015
```